# How do I change a state in the if codes? I've written these codes

Tags: reactjs, setstate

How can I use something like that

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        this.setState({slidesToShow:1})
    }else if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        this.setState({slidesToShow:2})
    }else  {
        this.setState({slidesToShow:3})
    }
});
```

But when I resize the page, the state doesn't change, and when it does, it does

Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: The reason for the error is you are not binding the `resize` function to instance of class. Use `resize = () => {}` arrow function or bind in constructor to correctly bind this` context.

Comment: Hi mohsen, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `addEventListener` on window in `componentDidMount`,

```
componentDidMount(){
   window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
}
```

Your resize function should be,

```
resize = () => {
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        this.setState({slidesToShow:1})
    }else if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
        this.setState({slidesToShow:2})
    }else  {
        this.setState({slidesToShow:3})
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qaktqy)

**Note:** Make sure to remove event listener when component unmounts,

```
componentWillUnmount(){
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I want to change the state value the first time it runs the way you said it only changes state if I resize the page.

Comment: @mohsenzarei, In that case you can directly call `this.resize()` in `componentDidMount` like, `componentDidMount(){
   this.resize();
   window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
}`

Comment: @mohsenzarei, Check the Demo, I have update it.

Comment: Thank you very much everything is working great

Answer (score 0):

In react you should do this in your render method like this and you need to use another if-else model, after '?' You should use your true state function and after ':' you should write your false function

```
Render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {windows.width() < 700 ?
        "Do something if true" 
        : 
        "do something if false " 
      }
   </div> 
  );
}
```

I don't test the code, but I hope it gives you the idea

Answer (score 0):

You could either add add and remove `resize` eventListener yourself or use `react-resize-detector` library.

1) Provides more flexibility. Can use as HOC, component or render prop pattern.

2) It also supports refresh mode(throttling and debouncing) and refresh rate which you had to support otherwise.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactResizeDetector from 'react-resize-detector';
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    slidesToShow: 1
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.slidesToShow}</div>
        <ReactResizeDetector handleWidth handleHeight onResize={this.onResize} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onResize = (width) => {
    if (width < 768) {
      this.setState({ slidesToShow: 1 });
    } else if (width < 992) {
      this.setState({ slidesToShow: 2 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ slidesToShow: 3 });
    }
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, rootElement);
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: What is point in repeating the same answer? What is new / change in your answer?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer.

Comment: It's alright. No need to be sorry. It happens. You can improve your answer if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have updated my answer.